# How does APP_OPTIM manifest in code?

Tags: android-ndk

In Application.mk you can set:

```
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_OPTIM := debug
```

How can I test for release/debug build in C++?

I'm assuming there are defines so I've tried this, but only "NOT" messages are logged:

```
#ifdef RELEASE
    LOGV("RELEASE");
#else
    LOGV("NOT RELEASE");
#endif

#ifdef DEBUG
    LOGV("DEBUG");
#else
    LOGV("NOT DEBUG");
#endif
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In `android-ndk-r8b/build/core/add-application.mk` we read:

```
ifeq ($(APP_OPTIM),debug)
  APP_CFLAGS := -O0 -g $(APP_CFLAGS)
else
  APP_CFLAGS := -O2 -DNDEBUG -g $(APP_CFLAGS)
endif
```

So, to answer your question: in NDK r8b (the latest for today) you can check

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
// this is "release"
#else
// this is "debug"
#endif
```

But you can add any other compilation flags through your `Android.mk` or `Application.mk` depending on $(APP_OPTIM), if you want.

Comment: So you always get the `-g` flag, even for a release build? And I was wondering why breakpoints work even for `APP_OPTIM:=release`.

Comment: @sashoalm: you can change that, if you wish, if you set `APP_CFLAGS := -g0` in **Application.mk**