# What optimizations does APP_OPTIM := release use?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I was looking for details on just how exactly `APP_OPTIM := release` optimizes code (e.g. what cflags it might use) and I came across this previous question: [How does APP_OPTIM manifest in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099931/how-does-app-optim-manifest-in-code)

However, when I search my ndk directory for the add-application.mk file, I noticed that I do not see the same code, instead, I have something like:

```
ifneq ($(APP_OPTIM),)
 # check that APP_OPTIM, if defined, is either 'release' or 'debug'
 $(if $(filter-out release debug,$(APP_OPTIM)),\
    $(call __ndk_info, The APP_OPTIM defined in $(_application_mk) must only be   'release' or 'debug')\
    $(call __ndk_error,Aborting)\
 )
 $(call ndk_log,Selecting optimization mode through Application.mk: $(APP_OPTIM))
else
```

And in particular, I have no idea what  `$(call ndk_log,Selecting optimization mode through Application.mk: $(APP_OPTIM))` is doing.

Can anyone direct me in the right direction to figure out just what sort of optimizations APP_OPTIM uses? Perhaps my ndk (r8e) has since moves that code block but I'm not sure where to find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should run `ndk-build` with parameter `V=1` to see exactly the compilation & link commands that it issues. Compare debug and release yourself.

Comment: Should I assume that the only difference between release and debug are in the compilation and link commands? Does that mean if I forced the compiler to use release flags like -O2 in debug mode, it will generate the same results?

Comment: Well, there are other flags in addition to `-O2`, including `-DDEBUG`. I actually use graphite optimizations and set `-O3` with gccc 4.7, but this cannot be done with blind eyes. Normally, debug mode turns off THUMB mode because step-by-step debugging in ARM mode is easier. Also, debug build puts the objects in `objs-debug` directory, so that switching from debug to release would not require clean rebuild.