# NDK use what flag for release lib

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, compiler-optimization

for some reason,my project use Jam to build my JNI code. we set the toolchains in NDK(currently we are using r10e) in our jam build system, which in end build out the SO file we need.
although it worked, but we are worrying we are not use the most correct/optimized flag. i do some research and guess 'ndk-build' by default will use following flag for release. is it correct? please let me know the correct flag. many thanks.

```
-fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
```

also, we just find that the math::pow(double,double) always return -0.0 on some device. it will be appreciated if you can give some comments.

Comment: are you looking for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13104129/192373)?

Comment: which device displays such special behavior of **`pow()`**?

Comment: Thanks for the info. Alex. i am using NDK r10e, i did not find the same code in add_application.mk, instead i find similar code in setup_common.mk.  can you confirm with me that 'ndk-build' is using the flags? i am currently customized to use -o3,while 'ndk-build' seems is using -o2 according to setup_common.mk.

Comment: for the pow() issue, it seems all device return wrong result. we have confirmed to be issue of our jam build. that is we use wrong flag or something else make the difference with 'ndk-build'. i will follow up this and share here if found the root reason.

Comment: I have no knowledge of Jam. You can always try `ndk-build V=1` to echo the actual compilation commands being used. Also, make sure your `pow()` is not redefined

Comment: Thanks Alex. ndk-build V=1 is very helpful for me. i want to accept this as answer. i found out the issue of pow, i am compiling with hard-float setting, while i used soft-float version gnustl_share so. after use correct gnustl_share, pow worked as expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time when you see some weird results (or error messages, or unexpected warnings) from Android NDK, don't underestimate the power of

```
ndk-build V=1
```

This will  echo all actual compilation commands being used.